# convert cidr to subnet mask in python

Tags: python, ip-address, subnet, cidr

I have a python dictionary that I've created, this dictionary contains a list of subnets in the following format:

```
x.x.x.x/24
y.y.y,y/25
z.z.z.z/26
a.a.a.a/27
```

etc...

I would like to take the items in this dictionary, parse it, then spit out the results in the following format:

```
x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0
y.y.y.y 255.255.255.128
x.x.x.x 255.255.255.192
a.a.a.a 255.255.255.224
```

I don't have much on this as of right now because I can't find a lot on this topic on the web, not anything that can be in a quick and concise way that is. Thoughts?

Comment: Your data is not dictionary as you mentioned!

Comment: If it helps to see an example, I made a class that does this [here](https://github.com/adamacosta/OMSCS-6250-Examples/blob/master/iputils/iputils.py).

Answer (score 15):

### Code:

```
import socket
import struct

def cidr_to_netmask(cidr):
    network, net_bits = cidr.split('/')
    host_bits = 32 - int(net_bits)
    netmask = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!I', (1 << 32) - (1 << host_bits)))
    return network, netmask
```

### Usage:

```
>>> cidr_to_netmask('10.10.1.32/27')
('10.10.1.32', '255.255.255.224')
>>> cidr_to_netmask('208.128.0.0/11')
('208.128.0.0', '255.224.0.0')
>>> cidr_to_netmask('208.130.28.0/22')
('208.130.28.0', '255.255.252.0')
```

Comment: Goes without saying, but for the IPv6 initiated. CIDR is the official notation for IPv6, there for netmask is not a thing anymore. But if you still wanted to, you could do it: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/148303f1677e56dcca794386e90299fc

Answer (score 11):

I thought I'd throw in my own solution, since I was going for a little bit more readability in it than the other answers shown.

```
def cidr_to_netmask(cidr):
  cidr = int(cidr)
  mask = (0xffffffff >> (32 - cidr)) << (32 - cidr)
  return (str( (0xff000000 & mask) >> 24)   + '.' +
          str( (0x00ff0000 & mask) >> 16)   + '.' +
          str( (0x0000ff00 & mask) >> 8)    + '.' +
          str( (0x000000ff & mask)))
```

It's now easier to see what's going on, and that is:

1. Get the numeric `mask` by padding the front with `1`s and having the `cidr` make up the rest
2. For each bit, apply the `mask`
3. Concatenate all the bits together, separated by periods

This is very procedural and does not use any libraries.

Answer (score 11):

Try this solution:

## Python3

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

networks = {'n1':'10.1.0.0/21','n2':'10.2.0.0/22','n3':'10.3.0.0/23','n4':'10.4.0.0/24'}

for x,y in enumerate(networks):
    print(IPv4Network(networks[y]).network_address, IPv4Network(networks[y]).netmask)
```

Result:

```
10.1.0.0 255.255.248.0
10.2.0.0 255.255.252.0
10.3.0.0 255.255.254.0
10.4.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

## Python2

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

networks = {'n1':'10.1.0.0/21','n2':'10.2.0.0/22','n3':'10.3.0.0/23','n4':'10.4.0.0/24'}

for x,y in enumerate(networks):
    print(str(IPNetwork(networks[y]).network), str(IPNetwork(networks[y]).netmask))
```

Result:

```
('10.1.0.0', '255.255.248.0')
('10.2.0.0', '255.255.252.0')
('10.3.0.0', '255.255.254.0')
('10.4.0.0', '255.255.255.0')
```

Comment: `apt install python-netaddr`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/ipaddress/ is a "Port of the 3.3+ ipaddress module to 2.6, 2.7, 3.2" in case you still need to maintain Python2 code and want to use `ipaddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lsIP = []
ans = 0
CIDR = 32
IP = [1] * CIDR
for i in range(len(IP)):
    iIdx = i % 8
    if iIdx == 0:
        if i >= 8:
            lsIP.append(ans)
            ans = 0
    ans += pow(2, 7 - iIdx)
lsIP.append(ans)

[lsIP.append(0) for i in range(4 - len(lsIP))]
print lsIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I made:

```
def cidr_to_netmask(cidr) -> str:
    cidr = int(cidr)
    mask_bin = f"{'1'*cidr}{'0'*(32-cidr)}"
    out = f"{int(mask_bin[0:8], 2)}.{int(mask_bin[8:16], 2)}.{int(mask_bin[16:24], 2)}.{int(mask_bin[24:32], 2)}"
    return out
```