# Is there a way of converting cidr to subnet mask in python ? I tried searching online but not getting the Exact answer

Tags: python, string, list, mask, subnet

my output is

print (network)

> > > ['10.202.224.0/24', '10.4.40.0/23', '10.3.41.0/24', '10.4.42.0/21']

can this be somehow converted to

> > > ['10.202.224.0/255.255.255.0', '10.4.40.0/255.255.254.0', '10.4.41.0/255.255.255.0', '10.4.42.0/255.255.248.0']

anything that helps converting the cidr to mask.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check out the python code for this may help you by clicking the link below:[this is the link to follow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33750650/17495768)

and the code is:

```
import socket
import struct

def cidr_to_netmask(cidr):
    network, net_bits = cidr.split('/')
    host_bits = 32 - int(net_bits)
    netmask = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!I', (1 << 32) - (1 << host_bits)))
    return network, netmask
```

usage:

```
>>> cidr_to_netmask('10.10.1.32/27')
('10.10.1.32', '255.255.255.224')
>>> cidr_to_netmask('208.128.0.0/11')
('208.128.0.0', '255.224.0.0')
>>> cidr_to_netmask('208.130.28.0/22')
('208.130.28.0', '255.255.252.0')
```

Comment: Hi Talha let me know if I am doing it correct as I am not getting any output                   import socket
import struct

cidr = ('10.2.5.6/28')


def cidr_to_netmask(cidr):
    network, net_bits = cidr.split('/')
    host_bits = 32 - int(net_bits)
    netmask = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!I', (1 << 32) - (1 << host_bits)))
    return network, netmask
    print(cidr)

Comment: after writing this code you have to pass value of cidr by calling the function name as i mentioned in usage . you can add one line below your existing "cidr_to_netmask(value_you_want_to_pass)"  description :first i have called function and passed value.