# Convert IPv4 CIDR to IP + subnet mask in python

Tags: python, cidr

First of all, sorry about my wording. I don't know how to explain properly but I try.

I have list of IP addresses like below.

```
1.1.1.0/25
2.2.2.0/27
3.3.0.0/22
```

and goes on like this. (each item is in different row in a txt file)

I want to another create a list but instead of /nn notation, I need to convert these into Subnet Masks.

such as

```
1.1.1.0 255.255.255.128
2.2.2.0 255.255.255.224
3.3.0.0 255.255.252.0
```

(to another txt file with each item in new line)

if you dont know subnet mask conversion thats fine, I can create a dictionary manually with keys and values however I am stuck at creating conversion of notations with enumarating existing list and converting into new list.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750233/convert-cidr-to-subnet-mask-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`ipaddress.ip_network()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_network).

```py
from ipaddress import ip_network

with open("in.txt") as i_f, open("out.txt", "w") as o_f:
    for line in i_f:
        network = ip_network(line.rstrip())
        print(network.network_address, network.netmask, file=o_f)
```

Comment: Or just use ```network.network_address``` as first argument to ```print```